# How to specify classes output directory for Gradle 4?

Tags: gradle

Gradle project deprecated 'classesDir' so the previously working method:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.classesDir = "myDir"
    }
}
```

should be replaced with something else. Documentation talks about 'output.classesDirs' but this is read-only property.

What is the method to specify **custom compilation output directory** in Gradle 4.x scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with java you can do this

```
 apply plugin: 'java'

 sourceSets {
   main {
     // Compiled Java classes should use this directory
     java.outputDir = file('myDir')
   }
 }
```

See more: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetOutput.html

Answer (score 0):

As per Gradle 6.5.1 docs the java.outputDir property is has been replaced by classesDirectory:

[Gradle 6.5.1 docs for SourceDirectorySet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet.html#org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet:destinationDirectory)

However I think that the destinationDirectory property should be used to read or modify the compiler output dir. So the docs should say that it is replaced by the destinationDirectory property rather than the classesDirectory property.

The compiler output directory can be changed using either of the following ways:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      destinationDirectory.set(file("${project.buildDir}/classes/${sourceSets.main.name}/java"))
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      destinationDirectory.value(project.getLayout().getBuildDirectory().dir("classes/${sourceSets.main.name}/java"));
    }
  }
}
```

In my opinion, the second option is better.

To read the output dir for a particular sourceSet use:

```
project.sourceSets.main.java.destinationDirectory.get()
```